# Create an manual twitter login and show profile ios app

Tags: twitter, authentication

I want to create an app to login into twitter, and then show user profile, I known how to show profile but I have to use account from setting. I want to create a login view, I found some information about xAuth and download a demo app, but it always have error 1012, another one is 401. Any other ways to login?
Please show me how to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure about what you want to achieve.

If you want to login on Twitter from an iOS application without using the account defined in Settings, then you can use the [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) library.

The demo project for iOS shows how to login through Safari.

You can also use consumer xAuth-enabled tokens and login directly with Twitter credentials.

Comment: Have a look at the sample code for OS X https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/84fddd0432342d5496fbf88599789f99d4006c8e/demo_osx/STTwitterDemoOSX/STAuthenticationVC.m#L281

Comment: Probably because your consumer tokens are not X-Auth enabled.